# [Artifactory-Jfrog]LDAP group is not synching

Tags: ldap, artifactory, group

I'm trying to sync LDAP group with Jfrog 7.41.7 community edition.
So far, I have successfully setup the LDAP settings and I'm able to login using a domain account.
Now, I'm trying to sync LDAP group using "LDAP group Settings", I'm always getting "Could not find DN for user: 'XXX'.
I tried to monitor the traffic using using wireshark and I can't see any ldap call done from Artifatory to the AD when I'm trying to sync.
Below is the current configuration I'm trying to apply :
[ldap group configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RY2h8.png)

Does any of you have an idea of the root cause of the problem ?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help !

Comment: Can you also share the LDAP setting screenshot by hiding the IP data? Also check the artifactory-service.log for any specific error and share it here.

Comment: @muhammed-kashif, sure. As of now, the ldap sync is working fine since I'm able to login using a domain credential : https://imgur.com/a/rhmyWRe

Comment: And within artifactory-request.log, I can see below trace when I'm quering for a group called "test :  2022-08-12T09:41:51.859Z|4dea6328bc0969ee|129.126.60.17|admin|POST|/api/ldapgroups/TEST/refresh/test|400|270|0|0|Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36. And no error visible in artifactory-service.log

Comment: I see the ldap setting is very basic and works for login purpose as Artifactory is able to get the user details, however, the ldap group sync is failing with 400 based on the log entry. Can you grep the entire log folder for this "4dea6328bc0969ee" thread id and share all the logs here?
Artifactory is getting 400 response which means the ldap group setting should be altered a bit to make it working.

Comment: Hi @muhammed-kashif, I can't find any specific folder/log file to this thread id, I only have some catalina log as well as artifactory-request.log regrouping all the request I did. Do you have any idea ? Thanks a tons for your reply on this topic !

Comment: Hi @muhammed-kashif, I think there is a bug on the community edition. I tried the same configuration on the pro version with a trial licence and the group is properly syncing

Comment: Hey @sigh it could be a bug then, can you raise it to the JFrog team over the Jira -- https://www.jfrog.com/jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Answer (score 1):

It's a pro version feature, check the log file `/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/log/access-service.log`, you will see the messages.

[jfac ] [WARN ] [11ca25a7ad5c7148] [.s.s.a.l.LdapSearchService:113] [7.0.0.1-8040-exec-10] - Search Ldap groups only supported for Pro license